# using Map to apply 2 lists to the LCM function - help

Tags: functions, map

I have 2 lists of numbers and I want to quickly compute the array of answers to the LCM function for the 2 lists and a 3rd static number.  I tried the following

```
list1 = {2,3,5,10};
list2 = {5,10,30,70};
LCM[37, #1, #2] & /@ [list1, list2]
```

but got a cryptic error message that I don't understand.  Can anyone help or point me to the correct area?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at `MapThread`.

Comment: Table came to the rescue.
    lcmResults = 
  ParallelTable[LCM[x, y, 37], {x, list1}, {y, list2}];

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Outer` along with `Map`.

```
Map[LCM[37, Sequence @@ #] &, Outer[List, list1, list2], {2}]
(*
{{370, 370, 1110, 2590}, 
 {555, 1110, 1110, 7770}, 
 {185, 370, 1110, 2590}, 
 {370, 370, 1110, 2590}}
*)
```

Hope this helps.

---

Or as @SimonWood has pointed out in the comments.

```
Outer[LCM[37, ##] &, list1, list2]
```

Comment: Why not just `Outer[LCM[37, ##] &, list1, list2]` ?

Comment: @SimonWoods Yes. You are completely correct. My solution-by-parts needs a convolution boost today. LOL!!

Comment: LOL. I wondered if you were just determined to use Map as specified in the question title...

Comment: @SimonWoods Perhaps subconsciously. :-P

Answer (score 2):

**Example:**

```
LCM[37, #[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{list1, list2}]
```

or

```
MapThread[LCM[37, ##] &, {list1, list2}]
```

**Output:**

```
{370, 1110, 1110, 2590}
```

**Reference:**

[& # /@](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) etc.
[MapThread](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html)
[Transpose](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html?q=Transpose)